# Angular Performance, Imports with Specific Path

Tags: angular, webpack, lodash

I'm trying to get down my bundle size. I ran [webpack-bundle-analyzer](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/webpack-bundle-analyzer) .

E.g. on the package `lodash` I get the following stats:

- Stat size 527.2kb
- Parsed size 69.14kb
- Gzipped 23.67kb

[Webpack size definitions](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/webpack-bundle-analyzer#size-definitions)

I import lodash methods in the following way:

`import {uniq, get, flatten} from 'lodash';`

## Question 1)

I'm not clear if I get any benefits from importing methods in a direct way e.g.:

`import {uniq} from 'lodash/uniq';`

Some [benchmark articles](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-correct-way-to-import-lodash-libraries-a-benchmark) write, that this reduces the bundle size. But e.g. with lodash this seems also to be achieved with a webpack plugin. As one can see in the above example the parsed size is a 10th of the stat size. So is this already done by angular?

## Question 2)

If 1) reduces the bundle size is there any better way than splitting the imports into multiple lines - which is imho quite cluttering the code.

```
import {uniq, get, flatten} from 'lodash';
```

=>

```
import {uniq, get, flatten} from 'lodash/uniq';
import {uniq, get, flatten} from 'lodash/get';
import {uniq, get, flatten} from 'lodash/flatten';
```

[ECAM6 imports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

## Question 3)

If I follow the recommendation of the direct import I just get an error

```
error TS2305: Module '"./frontend/node_modules/@types/lodash/difference"' has no exported member 'difference'.
```

Do I need to add a map for the lodash (and probably any other module I'm optimizing) in my `angular.json`?